# Multiple variables on one event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I use this code to check whether the value is empty, however, it's not working. Is it possible to set multiple variable in one event?

```
$('#date, #salesrep, #customer', '#repairamount').on('change', function(){  
    var date3 = $("#date3").val();
    var salesrep3 = $("#salesrep3").val();
    var customer3 = $("#customer3").val();
    var repairamount = $("#repairamount").val();
    if(date3==null || salesrep==null || customer3==null || repairamount==null) {
       $('#repairsubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
       $('#repairsubmit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what it is you're attempting to achieve. It's currently unclear.

Comment: `.val()` does not return `null`, but an empty string, or `undefined` if called on an empty collection. Try `''` instead, or simply `if (!date3 || !salesrep || !customer3 || !repairamount) { ... }`

Comment: @HanletEscaño add that as the answer

Comment: $('#date, #salesrep, #customer', '#repairamount').on('change', function(){   this function i think is not working

Comment: because i tried this $('#date') and its work but when i tried multiple its not working

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan Yeah that definitely looks strange. Why don't you also add the HTML here?